# Error in reorder(County, measure) : object 'County' not found

Tags: r, object

I have a data set I wish to use in R to produce a heat map. I used code for another heat map; that code works fine.

I would like to view the individual files that are created/used in the process. I assumed I could create a "new" data set using the "new_ds <- mutate(old_ds, commands) code and then write the new_ds to a csv file and look at it.  However the mutate command gives me an error as shown above in the title of this post. When I type view(ds), I can see the variable "County."   It is there. But when I use the class command, again I am told "County" is not found.

Here's the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
getwd()
lcn_fpf_co_names_copy <-read.csv("lcn_fpf_co_names_copy.csv")
mutate (County = reorder (County, measure))
Error in reorder(County, measure) : object 'County' not found
```

Why, if "County" is in the data set (which it is), does R tell me that object is not found?

The summary command gives these results, so you can see "County" is in the data set (I made it bold for emphasis):

```
summary(lcn_fpf_co_names_copy)

ENTRY          measure           SCORE           Svy_Year      Birth_Year       Gender          **County**      
 Min.   :    1   Min.   :  0.01   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   :2007   Min.   :1976   Min.   :1.000   Min.   : 1.000  
 1st Qu.: 4931   1st Qu.: 21.13   1st Qu.: 1.000   1st Qu.:2007   1st Qu.:1998   1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.: 5.000  
 Median : 9862   Median : 53.07   Median : 4.000   Median :2013   Median :2004   Median :1.000   Median : 9.000  
 Mean   : 9862   Mean   : 43.37   Mean   : 3.985   Mean   :2010   Mean   :2002   Mean   :1.487   Mean   : 8.491  
 3rd Qu.:14792   3rd Qu.: 60.25   3rd Qu.: 6.000   3rd Qu.:2013   3rd Qu.:2007   3rd Qu.:2.000   3rd Qu.:12.000  
 Max.   :19722   Max.   :100.00   Max.   :17.000   Max.   :2013   Max.   :2013   Max.   :2.000   Max.   :15.000  
   Co_Name              Region          UrbRur           Educ            Wealth     
 Length:19722       Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :1.000  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:1.000  
 Mode  :character   Median :3.000   Median :2.000   Median :0.0000   Median :2.000  
                Mean   :3.427   Mean   :1.702   Mean   :0.8083   Mean   :2.372  
                3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.:2.000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:3.000  
                Max.   :6.000   Max.   :2.000   Max.   :5.0000   Max.   :5.000
```

Any insights into this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since I don't know where the data comes from, I'm just guessing, but you have two 'county' like things, one appears to be called `**county**`, and another `Co_Name`, length: 19722, presumably names, that are the same al `Entry`, at least as to length. Thinking there are  3141 US counties or county equivalents, I've taken this as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Here we need the dataset name.  In the OP's code there was no connection with the `mutate` and the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
lcn_fpf_co_names_copy %>%
      mutate (County = reorder (County, measure))
```

Comment: Thank you, Akrun. The code ran. The file was not reordered. That's an issue, but at least I did not get the error message "Object not found."  I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @RJerome I think you need to assign the output back to `lcn_fpf_co_names_copy <- lcn_fpf_co_names_copy %>%
      mutate (County = reorder (County, measure))`